# Does a primary key contain exactly one Null value...?

Tags: primary-key, unique-constraint, dbms

My work

- A primary key is unique and only one contains for a table.
- There are many unique keys that can contain in a table.
- In SQL Server, the primary key is not Nullable. But, a unique key may contain only one null value.

My question:

Practically in SQL Server, the primary key is not nullable. But when it comes in theoretical, why don't we can have exactly only one Null value in the *primary* key when it allows a Null value in the unique key?

**Thanks for answering my question**

Sorry for asking a general question, after reading the answer I got a clear idea about null values in DB.

Also, I confused with programming languages like in C++, Jave, where the null value can be comparable. 
After doing some work, I understand that Null is not comparable in SQL.

> In programming languages like in C++, Jave...

```
Null==Null
```

returns TRUE

> But, in SQL

```
Null==Null
```

returns FALSE, because Null value is unknown and it could be any value.

Comment: `NULL = NULL` (or `NULL = anything`, actually) returns `NULL` instead of `FALSE`. A nuance, but it's important more often than you'd think.

Comment: NULL does not (SQL-)"equal" NULL in SQL but you can still "compare" 2 values in various ways where you get "true" when they are both NULL. Normal "equals" is expressed in standard SQL by IS NOT DISTINCT FROM.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No attribute that is part of a key can contain nulls; if a column is nullable then it isn't part of any key. It is also the case that the set of columns defined by a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY constraint is NOT a key unless it is a *minimal* superkey and also *non-nullable*.

Why can't keys permit nulls? There are lots of potential reasons:

1. Keys are a relational concept whereas nulls (as we know them today) are essentially a SQL invention which came along years later. SQL DBMSs are different to Relational DBMSs.
2. Nulls are not values so they are not key values. Nulls are markers for unspecified values.
3. Keys are supposed to be irreducible (minimal) - in other words all the components of the key are required to make a superkey. Since null means that some components are missing it contradicts this most basic definition of a key.
4. In standard SQL a uniqueness constraint does not enforce uniqueness if any column permits nulls.
5. SQL DBMSs also permit nulls in other constraints (except PRIMARY KEY): FOREIGN KEY, CHECK, ASSERTION. Nulls never violate the constraint so the null acts as a kind of "get out clause" for data integrity. Hypothetically, if nulls were permitted in keys then that would seem to imply a stricter form of referential integrity that didn't permit nulls in foreign keys unless there was a corresponding null key in the parent table. In that case every nullable foreign key would have to reference a nullable key and could not reference a non-nullable one.
6. There are no nulls in reality, in everyday mathematics or logic; they are just a programming feature in SQL and are not particularly "mathematical" or even consistent in the way they work. Don't look for more reasons: nulls work the way they do just because the designers of SQL say so.

Comment: Saying null is not a value (whatever that means) or that it is a marker (whatever that means) just promotes confusion & imprecision & is an impediment to clear thinking. Null is a value treated in a certain way by SQL syntax & operators. In "everyday mathematics or logic" anything can be a value, and null is a structureless everyday boring one like 7.

Comment: `In standard SQL a uniqueness constraint does not enforce uniqueness if any column permits nulls.` - see the thread following the question - apparently, the standard does not say this - multiple nulls **are** allowed for `UNIQUE` constraints! The thing everybody agrees on is that a `NULL` **cannot** be part of a `PRIMARY KEY`!

Comment: @Vérace "multiple nulls are allowed" is correct. That's what I mean when I say that uniqueness is not enforced. It's possible to have duplicate rows if you allow nulls so the rows won't necessarily be unique in the case of a nullable UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: @philipxy, Don't all values have the property of being equal to themselves? x=x is true if x is 7 but not if x is a null. Don't all values have the property of being not equal to other values? x='x is false if x is 7 but not if x is a null.

Comment: SQL `=` is not equals on scalars. It's like equals but it treats null differently. SQL `is not distinct from` is equals on scalars.

Comment: @philipxy, good point and you are absolutely right. But you see what I mean by "everyday". The usefulness of an information system surely depends on the ability of an average non-mathematician to understand it.

Comment: @Vérace "unique" & "distinct" are SQL terms that don't have their normal meanings. 2 values are SQL-distinct if they're not the same non-null value. An SQL-unique collection/bag of values is one where all are SQL-distinct from the others. But here nvogel is using the normal meaning. It's of course important to be clear about definitions of terms. [Re terms meaning different things in relational theory & SQL.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46024902/does-an-empty-sql-table-have-a-superkey-does-every-sql-table)

Comment: @philipxy My brother-in-law is a tiresome pedant in everything but where it counts - in this case it **does** count and your "pedantry" (in the positive sense of the term in the sense of wanting to clarify an important point!) in this case is justified!

Comment: Re. the quote from @nvogel `The usefulness of an information system surely depends on the ability of an average non-mathematician to understand it.` - I disagree with this - it's up to those of us who programme SQL to either have or obtain a grasp of the 3-value logic of `NULL`s and apply that when we write information systems! That's why we get paid the big bucks! (I wish - :-) ). One doesn't have to have a grasp of SQL to use an ATM, but the banks are using SQL in the background - Seán Citizen can remain oblivious to what the electrons are doing behind his cash withdrawal!

Comment: @Vérace, SQL is used by millions of information workers who are not professional programmers but who just want to write useful queries. You are right that the ones who are programmers have to spend a lot of time hiding the complexity of things like 3VL from the people who use their systems. Unfortunately many highly experienced SQL developers don't have a good understanding of advanced SQL topics like 3VL either - not least because different DBMSs implement different rules.